# c how to copy hexadecimal value into array using memcpy

Tags: c

I am working with `C`, and I have a `uint8_t array` of `hex` values and I want to add another value to it via `memcpy` dynamically e.g.

I have an array: `uint8_t sample['0x23', '0x34',...]` e.t.c.
...and I want to copy another `Hex character` into the `array` later on. How is this done? If this question has been answered before, sorry, I couldn't find it. I am new to `C`, and these `pointers` are giving me hell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: um what? `'0x23'` is not one byte. Are you trying to copy bytes? Characters? Are you trying to convert hexadecimal string representations to numbers or vice versa? If you know you can use `memcpy()` to copy between memory blocks, what's the problem? This is very unclear and missing a lot of context.

Comment: There is no such thibg as hexadecimal value. It's like writing the number 8 in geen ink and calling it a green eight. An uint8_t holds an uint8_t value, not hexadecimal or decimal or green or whatever.

Comment: @n.m.: Yes, `0x23` fits in a byte. `'0x23'` is a multi-character constant with an implementation-defined value; it very probably doesn't fit in a byte.

Comment: @n.m. `0x23` does but `'0x23'` (which is a so-called **multi-byte** character literal) does not.

Comment: @Peter Why not to write simply sample[4] = '\x0A';?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant yes, but then `[x,y,z]` is not a C array either. So we are squarely in the fantasy notation land.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow why would that be simpler?

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant At least because there is no need to use the function and a string literal.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but why is `'\x0A'` simpler than `0xA`? It requires extra escaping and quotes.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant Wkth a character array I prefer to use character constants. This is more informative for a reader.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But it's not a character array. It's a byte array. That's conceptually different. Also, "it's simpler because I prefer it" is not a logical reasoning. It's just *not simpler.* It's even slightly less readable.

Comment: @ The Paramagnetic Croissant In fact it is a character array. I clearly wrote that it is simpler to use the assignment instead of function memcpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write simply

```
sample[4] = '\x0A';
```

If you want to use memcpy then the valid code will look like

```
memcpy( &sample[4], "\x0A", 1 );
```

or

```
memcpy( sample + 4, "\x0A", 1 );
```

That is you need to use string literal instead of character constant.

Comment: Haha, totally like this. How embarrassing, I was too fixated on memcpy to remember the basics. Thanks @Vlad

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if what is really being asked is how to add a new value to the end of the array.

In C, there is no "array" class, so you must either manage the memory and associated pointers yourself, or use a pre-defined function library that does it all for you.  Let's assume the former i.e. the programmer is doing the management themselves.

Before you can assign or copy a new value into your array, you'll need to ensure there is enough space.  One way to manage this follows:

```
int     array_size = 10;
uint8_t sample[array_size];
uint8_t i = 4;    /* assuming array index cannot exceed 255 */

if (i < array_size) {
    sample[i] = 0x0a;
}
```

The key here is that your sample array occupies just 10 bytes of memory and you need to make sure that your accesses to the sample array do not fall outside that bound.

If indeed the desire is to append a value to the end of the array, then another variable will have to be added to keep track of the last insertion point/index and use that for `i` in the example.

Comment: No. the aim wasn't to just add a value to the end of the array, the aim was to add a value at any position within the array which I wanted to get the final array in a specific logical arrangement for me.